CPU Hardware GHZ limit is less than Windows GHZ limit[Laptop modelAO725, Lubuntu 24.04.1]
unknown@Unknown:~$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1000 MHz
  available frequency steps: 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.00 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1000 MHz:82.99%, 800 MHz:17.01%  (128)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1000 MHz
  available frequency steps: 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.14 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1000 MHz:91.49%, 800 MHz:8.51%  (158)

The maximum limit in windows 7 was 1.3 Ghz but it is less 800-1000Mhz in Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Nobel Numbat, I am wondering if installing a suitable proietieary display driver will solve this problem, the current display driver is open-source driver AMD Wrestler 6290 HD. IF yes someone please tell me a propietary driver to install for AO725 model since additional driver sections shows no propietary driver to install.
